# How to upload the entire folder in Joomla 2.5

Tags: upload, module, joomla2.5

Hello I am new to Joomla CMS. i Want to upload a entire folder to another new folder. There is any extension or modules are available.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have ftp access the best joomla file manager module for me is [eXtplorer](http://extplorer.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

crete ftp connection via total commander or another program and you can easily transfer files and folders